# Do antisense transcripts have different names than their sense strand transcripts?

Tags: genetics, genomics, mrna

I want to find which genes in the human genome can potentially be complementary to a transcript that could act as antisense transcript inhibtion? Are cis-NATs (naturally occuring anti-sense transcripts) considered different transcripts and named differently or do they have the same name as the sense transcript?

Answer (score 6):

*If* the anti-sense transcript is correctly annotated and in the databases (a very very big if), then it will have a different name. For example, the mouse Msx1 anti-sense transcript has the RefSeq accession [NR_027920](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NR_027920?report=GenBank) while the sense transcript of the same gene is [NM_010835](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_010835?report=GenBank).

In general, each transcript that is transcribed from a given locus has a different accession. The same is true for alternatively spliced transcripts. If a given gene has 4 AS transcripts, each of these transcripts will have a different, unique accession. The human insulin receptor gene, for example, has two protein coding transcripts, each with its own accession: [NM_000208](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_000208) and [NM_001079817](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_001079817).

You may be interested in a recent analysis of cis-NATs in 10 species[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1534/genetics.106.069484) and also in [NATsDB](http://natsdb.cbi.pku.edu.cn/): Natural Antisense Transcripts DataBase[<sup>[2]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkn470).

1. [**Osato N, Suzuki Y, Ikeo K, Gojobori T**. 2007. Transcriptional Interferences in *cis* Natural Antisense Transcripts of Humans and Mice. Genetics, 176(2): 1299-1306, doi:10.1534/genetics.106.069484.](http://natsdb.cbi.pku.edu.cn/)
2. [**Li JT, Zhang Y, Kong L, Liu QR, Wei L**. 2008. *Trans*-natural antisense transcripts including noncoding RNAs in 10 species: implications for expression regulation. Nucleic Acids Research, 36(15):4833-44, doi:10.1093/nar/gkn470.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkn470)